# Call local domain from React Native and expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, wampserver

I have local website, with Wampserver and Windows (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` edited).

> http://myproject.local

**This site works great from my computer.**

Now, I want create mobile application with React Native and Expo.

But, in my mobile app, when I call my website :

```
export function getForumIndex () {
    const url = 'http://myproject.local/api/test'

    return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
}
```

I have this error :

> [21:29:58] JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'
>   node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
>   node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in unknown
>   ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

I think my phone and expo can not call the API on my computer (http://myproject.local/api/test). I am a beginner in mobile application. When I test with [TMDb API](https://www.themoviedb.org/?language=fr) it works well.

I do not know how to do it, can you help me ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your application is running on your mobile phone, you need to connect to your computer over the network. The best way to do this is to connect both your phone and computer to the same wifi network, then replace `myproject.local` with the local IP address your computer has for the wifi network it's connected to e.g `http://192.168.1.1/api/test` where `192.168.1.1` is replaced by the local IP address for your computer. You can follow [these steps](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/windows-7/find-your-local-ip-address-windows-7-cmd/) for finding your local IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing locally. You will need to use the Local IP of your machine.

First, open the Command Prompt and do
`ipconfig`
Note the IPV4 address, that will be your local ip to use for your AP urI such http://192.168.10.100:80/api/test.php

Answer (score 0):

you have to use your machine's ip address,

Comment: This is the same solution as in [Lewa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070830/2227743) and the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Actual response is not a json server is rendering html page.
So your getting JSON parse exception.

Instead of response json()
try using
console.log(response.text())

In that log you will get html code in that you can get what is the error.